# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. while calling alchemy api through mashape

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, alchemy

```
public class keywords
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
   public string text { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "relevance")]
   public string relevance { get; set; }
}
public class JsonData
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
   public string status { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "usage")]
   public string usage { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]

   public string url { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "language")]
   public string language { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty ("keywords")]
   public keywords keyword { get; set; }     
}
```

above are the classes i am using to deserialize the json response being received by calling the alchemy API.

```
string url =     "https://alchemy.p.mashape.com/Text/TextGetRankedKeywords?outputMode=json&text=" + text;
var response = (Unirest.get("https://alchemy.p.mashape.com/Text/TextGetRankedKeywords?outputMode=json&text=" + text)
   .header("X-Mashape-Key", "AlZVYH30C9mshLPNM7KiE48aFfTHp1h3A31jsnmVPccxBzW5uB")
   .header("Accept", "application/json")
   .asJson<JsonData>()
   .Body);
var status = response.keyword.text;
var score = response.keyword.relevance;
```

I am getting this error:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: Please fix the code formatting

Comment: i have fixed the code formatting

Comment: Can you please post the data that is sent to the service?

Comment: "status": "OK",
  "usage": "By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html",
  "totalTransactions": "1",
  "language": "english",
  "keywords": [
    {
      "relevance": "0.951162",
      "text": "homeland"
    },
    {
      "relevance": "0.814847",
      "text": "pakistan"
    },
    {
      "relevance": "0.580087",
      "text": "country"
    }
  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was making an error in url. url was "https://alchemy.p.mashape.com/text/TextGetRankedKeywords?outputMode=json&text="
moreover i was required to make array instance of keywords object in JsonData class